# Paypal server side integration in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, paypal, payment-gateway

I am unable to follow [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK#configuration).I want to use it in my django application. Can you please show me how to use these things or where to place those code. Or if you have any other ways to integrate the paypal payment gateway(server side) in python, Please help me!!

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The one which you referring to is deprecated, I'd reckon to use the below latest Python SDK.

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned that SDK is deprecated, use the Checkout-Python-SDK.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

If on success you want to go over to a thank you or confirmation page or something similar, put such a redirect in the bottom success section of that JavaScript's response/error handler.